# trying to take code into exe demo

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, exe

I'm developing a product idea.

I sketched out comps and wireframes.

Paid a developer a small sum to code it for use as a demonstration in pitch meetings, etc.

it's written in HTML5, CSS and JavaScript.

Dev sent me a zip file with the HTML, CSS, .JS, and images. When I open the HTML file, it works as advertised in my desktop browser.  (I can even simulate what it might look like on mobile by using XCode iOS simulator)

What I really want, however, is to allows others do demo it as an executable file on their devices. Presumably by clicking a link.

How do I do this? Where can I upload these HTML, CSS, .JS, and image files somewhere, and have a link cause them to execute?

Comment: Isn't that just a normal website? Buy a domain name, host the site with a company and there you go...

Comment: You need to host the website or send them the files and tell them to click on the 'index.html' file to start the site.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a domain and web host and upload the files using something like FTP. If you buy a domain and webhost package, it's generally as simple as that.

Tell the users you're demonstrating at to visit the domain you've purchased once you've uploaded the files.

Alternatively, you could host it locally using IIS, Apache or XAMPP (which is a wrapper of existing technologies, including Apache - it is also the easiest option) and have them enter your IP Address to demo the site.

Comment: strongly recommend mamp for this - if you're not an expert it's the easiest solution. Just turn it on, point it at a folder, and you're good